# Can a skin alter the hitboxes on a hero?

Tags: overwatch

Can different skins affect the hitboxes on heroes? For example, with Zenyatta, the Ifrit skin adds a headpiece. Is this now an area that can take damage?

Can skins increase the effective headshot hitbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, all skins have the same hitbox. I've seen this from playing against Zenyatta using legendary skins.

Comment: For Zenyatta then, would hurtboxes pass through (the iris) the headgear at the top of his head? So for Reinhardt, the skin that removes his helmet, the hitbox stays the same? Just trying to cover all bases here.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Yes, all skins are exactly the same in terms of hitbox. The helmet (or its removal) does not affect the head's size.

Comment: It's worth noting that the hitboxes are larger than the base models- this could be in part to allow all the different skins to have some form of unique shaping, but still be fully enclosed in the hit box (no shot clipping). That said- with the Widowmaker Noire skin, you can clip through her ponytail if you shoot it while she's jumping.